# How do I know which UDP packets I have already received?

Tags: networking, udp, client-server

I am making a game using a client-server model with UDP. Here's how I have implemented it so far:

- All packets include a sequence number and a flag specifying whether they are "important".
- Important message types require acknowledgement and will be re-sent after a delay if no acknowledgement is received.
- Most message types are "unimportant" - that is, they do not require an acknowledgement, and if such a message is received with an older sequence number than the latest, it is dropped.

My dilemma is this: if an "important" message arrives twice, I only want to process it once. But how will I know that I have already received it, without keeping an ever-expanding list in memory?

**Ideas**

1. Just remember the last *X* "important" messages received - the likelihood of receiving a VERY old message is slim (not ideal as it's not 100% reliable).
2. Use TCP for "important" messages (not ideal due to the complications and overhead involved in managing 2 protocols simultaneously).
3. Have a separate sequence number for "important" messages and ensure that these are always received in order, so only the most recent message needs to be remembered (I'm leaning towards this).
4. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use #3. The fact that you are ACK-ing the important messages provides the mechanism to ensure they are received in order, i.e. don't ACK an out-of-sequence one, and just remember the sequence number of the last one you ACK-ed.

Comment: not ACK'ing the out-of-sequence message would cause a delay for all the other received messages in the timeout window. I'd go for this solution only if you cannot manage to store a bunch of messages in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Have a separate sequence number for "important" messages (starting from zero), and the following variables:

- a variable `min_recv`, indicating that you received all "important" messages from 0 to `min_recv` (excluded);
- a list of the "important" sequence number that you already have received.

At any time (e.g. after receiving another "important" message), you store its sequence number in the list; then you can check if you can compact the list:

```
while list contains `min_recv`:
    remove `min_recv` from list
    increment min_recv
```

In this way you consume minimal memory, because even when you receive out-of-order important messages (and the size of the list will start to grow), eventually you will receive the missing message, because it will be retransmitted if lost, and you will empty the list.

Comment: Thank you for this, it sounds like a good way to support out-of-order messages with guaranteed delivery.